# will answers here form part of the homestead documentation initiative?

Tags: discussion

is there a mechanism / procedure / plan for the top answers here on specific subjects to be included in the new [Ethereum Homestead Documentation](https://ethereum-homestead.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
 - (starting to populate very shortly) - [see the sticky post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/42vuik/homestead_documentation_initiative/)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "official" plan for this, but suggestions for oft-asked questions would be helpful. If you want to contribute, jump into the [Homestead documentation Gitter room](https://gitter.im/ethereum/homestead-guide) and add your thoughts